# Keyboard shortcut highjacked with VSCode to trigger TypeScript props

Tags: keyboard

I can't use the `^ space` shortcut on VSCode.

Here is the behaviour I want to have (*but it's associated with the wrong shortcut here it's `⇧ space`*):

[image]

1. I already landed on the apple forum to [free Control-Space for binding](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8507324?sortBy=best) (*I even changed the Input source shortcut to a random one*)

[image: unselect input source macOS]

2. with VSCode I want to add the combinaison `^ space` but i can't

[image]

I am 100% sure it was working before, but somehow it's broken now with Sonoma 14.2.1.

How can I know if another application is hijacking the shortcut? or how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.

Here is what I have done:

1. download [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) to start a fresh install
2. Noticed the shortcut works

So I thought the problem was coming from my extensions.

- I relaunched VSCode

```
Extensions: Disable All Installed Extensions for this Workspace
```

- Setup again `Trigger.Suggest` with `^ space`
- Activate extensions one by one.